# HTML/PHP Contact form goes to success page but I get no email or errors

Tags: php, html, forms

Hello I'm new to stackoverflow so forgive me if I'm doing anything wrong. Also I have very little knowledge on PHP. So I have this contact form that I want to send to my email when the user submits it. I have been beating my head against the wall for a while now, both files are uploaded to the server, and are in the same directory. The form goes to the success page, but I get no email. HELP ME PLEASE!

Also the link to the form is http://xtcracingteam.com/apply.html if that helps.

This is the HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="http://xtcracingteam.com/send_form_email.php">
    <label class="first-name">First Name</label>
    <input name="firstName" class="firstName" type="text" placeholder="Joe" required />
    <label class="last-name">Last Name</label>
    <input name="lastName" class="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Swanson" required />
    <label class="Race-number">Race Number</label>
    <input name="raceNumber" class="raceNumber" type="text" placeholder="999" required />
    <label class="class">Class</label>
    <input name="bikeClass" class="bikeClass" type="text" placeholder="Mx 450 Production A" required />
    <label class="age">Age</label>
    <input name="personAge" class="personAge" type="text" placeholder="21" required />
    <label class="home-town">Home Town</label>
    <input name="homeTown" class="homeTown" type="text" placeholder="Washougal Washington" required />
    <label class="Current-sponsors">Current Sponsors</label>
    <textarea name="sponsors" placeholder="Gopro, Redbull, Scott..." class="currentSponsors" required></textarea>
    <label class="recent-achievements">Recent Achievements</label>
    <textarea name="recentAchievments" placeholder="I won this and that..." class="recentAchievments" required></textarea>
    <label class="why">Why should we pick you to represent our brand?</label>
    <textarea name="theWhy" placeholder="(hint: Dont say Cuz im the fastest)" class="theWhy" required></textarea>
    <label class="email">Email</label>
    <input name="email" class="email" type="email" placeholder="Example@emails.com" required />
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php
    ini_set(‘display_errors’, ‘On’);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
        // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
        $email_to = "xtc.racing.team@gmail.com";
        $email_subject = "New Application";

        function died($error) {
            // your error code can go here
            echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted.        ";
            echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
            echo $error."<br /><br />";
            echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
            die();
        }

        // validation expected data exists
        if(!isset($_POST['firstName']) ||
            !isset($_POST['lastName']) ||
            !isset($_POST['raceNumber']) ||
            !isset($_POST['bikeClass']) ||
            !isset($_POST['personAge']) ||
            !isset($_POST['homeTown']) ||
            !isset($_POST['sponsors']) ||
            !isset($_POST['recentAchievments']) ||
            !isset($_POST['theWhy']) ||
            !isset($_POST['email'])) {
            died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you  submitted.');       
        }

        $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
        $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
        $raceNumber = $_POST['raceNumber']; // required
        $bikeClass = $_POST['bikeClass']; // required
        $personAge = $_POST['personAge']; // required
        $homeTown = $_POST['homeTown']; // required
        $sponsors = $_POST['sponsors']; // required
        $recentAchievments = $_POST['recentAchievments']; // required
        $theWhy = $_POST['theWhy']; // required
        $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

        function clean_string($string) {
            $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
            return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
        }

        $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($firstName)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($lastName)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
        $email_message .= "race number: ".clean_string($raceNumber)."\n";
        $email_message .= "bikeClass: ".clean_string($bikeClass)."\n";
        $email_message .= "personAge: ".clean_string($personAge)."\n";
        $email_message .= "homeTown: ".clean_string($homeTown)."\n";
        $email_message .= "sponsors: ".clean_string($sponsors)."\n";
        $email_message .= "recentAchievments: ".clean_string($recentAchievments)."\n";
        $email_message .= "theWhy: ".clean_string($theWhy)."\n";

        // create email headers
        $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
        'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

return to <a href="http://xtcracingteam.com">XTCRacingTeam</a>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Does the server have an SNMP module? Or some sort of email server to actually perform that function?

Comment: Remove the `@` before `mail` to see what error message mail is returning.

Comment: For sending emails, you may consider using one of the many established mail libraries out there. I usually use this one: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Comment: sorry I removed the @ and still no errors

Comment: You are not actually checking for failure or success. What does the `mail()` function return, `true` or `false`?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you checked to see if it's going into your spam folder?

Comment: Yes i checked my spam and unfortunately no luck.. How do I check for true or false in php? (sorry php new guy here)

Comment: `$success = mail(.....); var_dump($success);`

Comment: it says its true "bool(true)"

Comment: The email was accepted for delivery then. Note that your variables don't match. Some have underscores and uppercase letters that are missing later on, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

When you are debugging your code, debug it step by step in smaller portions.

I.e. try:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

to see what are you getting from your form.

try sending an email using the mail() function and putting in hardcoded data instead of the vars.

Also, try

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

mail() returns a bool, even if the mail server rejects the sending.

if(mail()) { echo 'succes'; } else { echo 'no success'; }
```